Compute column value based on previous row recursively
Given the following scheme and values I want to compute the value of each row starting by adding 1 to the previous row value. If the row value is null then set null. If there is a value then add 1 from the previous value.
How can I achieve this in Postgres?
I've tried recursive CTE but without success.
Input data:
symbol  date                    close   computed
TBBB    2024-02-22 14:30:00+00  19.05   
TBBB    2024-02-23 14:30:00+00  19.55   
TBBB    2024-02-24 14:30:00+00  20.6    
TBBB    2024-02-25 14:30:00+00  21.3    
TBBB    2024-02-26 14:30:00+00  20.43   20.4
TBBB    2024-02-27 14:30:00+00  20.21   
TBBB    2024-02-28 14:30:00+00  20.74   
TBBB    2024-02-29 14:30:00+00  20.09   
TBBB    2024-03-01 14:30:00+00  20.79   
TBBB    2024-03-02 14:30:00+00  20.87   
TBBB    2024-03-03 14:30:00+00  20.69   
TBBB    2024-03-04 14:30:00+00  20.19   
TBBB    2024-03-05 14:30:00+00  20.9    
TBBB    2024-03-06 14:30:00+00  20.99   
TBBB    2024-03-07 14:30:00+00  21.28   
TBBB    2024-03-08 14:30:00+00  21.27   

Expected result:
symbol  date                    close   computed
TBBB    2024-02-22 14:30:00+00  19.05   
TBBB    2024-02-23 14:30:00+00  19.55   
TBBB    2024-02-24 14:30:00+00  20.6    
TBBB    2024-02-25 14:30:00+00  21.3    
TBBB    2024-02-26 14:30:00+00  20.43   20.4
TBBB    2024-02-27 14:30:00+00  20.21   21.4
TBBB    2024-02-28 14:30:00+00  20.74   22.4
TBBB    2024-02-29 14:30:00+00  20.09   23.4
TBBB    2024-03-01 14:30:00+00  20.79   24.4
TBBB    2024-03-02 14:30:00+00  20.87   25.4
TBBB    2024-03-03 14:30:00+00  20.69   26.4
TBBB    2024-03-04 14:30:00+00  20.19   27.4
TBBB    2024-03-05 14:30:00+00  20.9    28.4
TBBB    2024-03-06 14:30:00+00  20.99   29.4
TBBB    2024-03-07 14:30:00+00  21.28   30.4
TBBB    2024-03-08 14:30:00+00  21.27   31.4

The +1 from previous value is just for simplicity. In reality I would have a math formula there.
What I've tried:
Some simpler example and not related to the question: here I calculate the computed column based on the close. This was a initial example, it's not what I want:
WITH computed_values AS (SELECT symbol,
                           date,
                           close,
                           CASE
                               WHEN LAG(computed, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY date) IS NULL THEN null
                               ELSE (close * (2.0 / (period + 1))) +
                                    (LAG(computed, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY date) * (1 - (2.0 / (period + 1))))
                               END AS computed
                    FROM (SELECT symbol,
                                 date,
                                 close,
                                 close AS computed,
                                 5     AS period
                          FROM my_table
                          WHERE symbol = 'TBBB' 
                          ORDER BY date) subquery)
SELECT *
FROM computed_values;

Generated by AI and not working:
WITH NumberedRows AS (
    SELECT 
        symbol, 
        date, 
        close,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS row_num
    FROM my_table
),
KnownClose AS (
    SELECT 
        symbol, 
        date, 
        close,
        row_num
    FROM NumberedRows
    WHERE close IS NOT NULL
),
RecursiveClose AS (
    SELECT 
        symbol,
        date,
        close,
        row_num
    FROM KnownClose
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        nr.symbol,
        nr.date,
        rc.close - 2 AS close,
        nr.row_num
    FROM RecursiveClose rc
    JOIN NumberedRows nr ON nr.row_num = rc.row_num - 1
    WHERE nr.close IS NULL
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        nr.symbol,
        nr.date,
        rc.close + 2 AS close,
        nr.row_num
    FROM RecursiveClose rc
    JOIN NumberedRows nr ON nr.row_num = rc.row_num + 1
    WHERE nr.close IS NULL
) SELECT symbol,
    date,
    close
FROM RecursiveClose
ORDER BY row_num;


(a) You're supposed to post the details in the question and (b) give an example of expected data and (c) show what you've tried so far

This is one of the rare cases that lends itself to a procedural solution.
Replace all instances of tbl with your actual (schema-qualified) table name:
-- create function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_compute()
  RETURNS SETOF tbl
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r  tbl; -- use table type as row variable
   r0 tbl;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM tbl t ORDER BY t.symbol, t.date
   LOOP
      IF r.symbol = r0.symbol            -- same symbol
      AND r0.computed IS NOT NULL        -- last computed exists
      AND r.computed IS NULL THEN        -- this computed is null
         r.computed := r0.computed + 1;  -- your computation here
      END IF;
      RETURN NEXT r;
      r0 := r;                           -- remember last row
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;

Call:
SELECT * FROM f_compute();

fiddle
Produces exactly your desired result. Compare performance with EXPLAIN ANALYZE.
Related:

GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values
Group by repeating attribute

If you don't want to persist a function, consider a temporary function. See:

How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?


how the function will change if the first computed value is average of close values?
for example instead of  20.4 computed value is as "select round(avg(close), 2) from (select * from stock_prices sp where symbol = 'TBBB' order by time asc limit 5) ppp

@florin Please give some feedback on the answers to this question first. Does it work for you? How does performance compare? Once this question is answered, ask your new question as new question. You can always link to this one for context (and drop a comment here to get my attention for the new question.

This should work:

; with recursive NumberThem as (
   select symbol
        , dte
        , clse
        , computed
        , row_number() over (partition by symbol order by dte) as rn
   from MyTbl
   ),
   CTE as (
    select 
         symbol
       , dte
       , clse
       , a.rn
       , a.computed as rcomputed
    from NumberThem a
    where rn=1
    union all
    select 
        a.symbol
      , a.dte
      , a.clse
      , a.rn
      , coalesce(a.computed,CTE.rcomputed+1) as rcomputed
    from CTE 
         inner join
         NumberThem a
         on CTE.symbol=a.symbol
         and CTE.rn+1=a.rn
)
select * 
from CTE

I numbered the rows by date for ease of referencing, then used a recursive CTE to start from the earliest date (row number) and access each row sequentially by incrementing it.

You can do this purely using window functions. Unfortunately, Postgres does not support IGNORE NULLS, which would have made it simpler. Instead we need to hack it with array_agg and FILTER.

Compute a row-number.
Conditionally aggregate (in a running window) both the computed column and the row-number, only when computed is not null.
Take the last element of the computed array, add the current row-number and subtract the last element of the row-number array.

WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.date) AS rn
    FROM my_table mt
),
arrayed AS (
    SELECT *,
      array_agg(mt.computed) FILTER (WHERE mt.computed IS NOT NULL) OVER running_date AS array_computed,
      array_agg(mt.rn) FILTER (WHERE mt.computed IS NOT NULL) OVER running_date AS array_rn
    FROM ranked mt
    WINDOW running_date AS (ORDER BY mt.date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
)
SELECT *,
  coalesce(
    mt.computed,
    mt.array_computed[array_upper(mt.array_computed, 1)]
    + mt.rn
    - mt.array_rn[array_upper(mt.array_rn, 1)]
  ) AS new_computed
FROM arrayed mt;

db<>fiddle
